# Unable to plot function with exponentials or to find all roots

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am not able to

```
Plot[(-1)^x + 2^x - 2 x - 1, {x, -4, 4}]
```

directly. Some rework might be needed with complex branch cuts perhaps.

There are real roots at $ x=3, x=2  $. I configured this expression with the first root 3 and there are several other concomitant complex roots. It comes to me as a surprise so with the infallible *Mathematica*. What may be something that I miss? I wish to be able to see the plot and all roots in the domain with your help.

Comment: What on Earth led you to believe that *Mathematica* is infallible?

Comment: Here's a start on the roots: `NSolve[(-1)^x + 2^x - 2 x - 1 == 0 && -4 < Re@x < 4 && -1 < Im@x < 1, x]`

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to read off roots from the graph.... we read them off simply as x,y components where two graphs cut, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are plotting a complex function, as you know, so you need to plot the real and imaginary parts separately.

```
Plot[ReIm[(-1)^x + 2^x - 2 x - 1], {x, -4, 4}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can get some help on this from Wolfram Alpha, if you start your expression with two equal signs:

[image]

This shows that you need to plot the real and imaginary parts separately.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt check for [Complexes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complexes.html),

```
FunctionDomain[(-1)^x + 2^x - 2 x - 1, x, Complexes]
```

> True

```
FunctionRange[(-1)^x + 2^x - 2 x - 1, x, Complexes]
```

> -2. <= Complexes <= 4.25

```
ComplexExpand[(-1)^x + 2^x - 2 x - 1, x]
```

> $e^{-\pi  \Im(x)} \cos (\pi  \Re(x))+i \left(e^{-\pi  \Im(x)} \sin
> > (\pi  \Re(x))+2^{\Re(x)} \sin (\log (2) \Im(x))-2
> > \Im(x)\right)+2^{\Re(x)} \cos (\log (2) \Im(x))-2 \Re(x)-1$

Find Re and Im,

```
sol1 = ComplexExpand[Re[(-1)^x + 2^x - 2 x - 1]]
```

> $-2 x+2^x+\cos (\pi  x)-1$

```
sol2 = ComplexExpand[Im[(-1)^x + 2^x - 2 x - 1]]
```

> $\sin (\pi  x)$

Have a plot:

```
Plot[sol1 - sol2, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

And solve for roots:

```
eqn = sol1 - sol2
```

> $-2 x+2^x-\sin (\pi  x)+\cos (\pi  x)-1$

```
soln = NSolve[{eqn, 2 <= x <= 4}, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 2.}, {x -> 3.}}

And you can plot the Functions:

```
Plot[{sol1, sol2}, {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[eqn, {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Nice Plot if you need to viz other roots:

```
Plot[{eqn, -eqn}, {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image]